# Symfony2 delete the "if-modified-since" parameter on production

Tags: php, symfony, http-headers, if-modified-since

I made a API with Symfony2 for a iOS-App. The App send a GET request with the header-parameter `if-modified-since`

> "If-Modified-Since" = "Thu, 07 Nov 2013 11:50:52 GMT";

In the controller I check the parameter and return the data if the date is newer. But in Symfony2 the Parameter would be deleted on the production environment in the class `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\HttpCache.php`. Here is the function in the class.

```
/**
 * Forwards the Request to the backend and determines whether the response should be stored.
 *
 * This methods is triggered when the cache missed or a reload is required.
 *
 * @param Request $request A Request instance
 * @param Boolean $catch   whether to process exceptions
 *
 * @return Response A Response instance
 */
protected function fetch(Request $request, $catch = false)
{
    $subRequest = clone $request;

    // send no head requests because we want content
    $subRequest->setMethod('GET');

    // avoid that the backend sends no content
    $subRequest->headers->remove('if_modified_since');
    $subRequest->headers->remove('if_none_match');

    $response = $this->forward($subRequest, $catch);

    if ($this->isPrivateRequest($request) && !$response->headers->hasCacheControlDirective('public')) {
        $response->setPrivate(true);
    } elseif ($this->options['default_ttl'] > 0 && null === $response->getTtl() && !$response->headers->getCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate')) {
        $response->setTtl($this->options['default_ttl']);
    }

    if ($response->isCacheable()) {
        $this->store($request, $response);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

So it looks like Symfony doesn't find a cache entry for this response of the request and delete this parameter to be sure, that there will be content to cache, but he never find a entry. Also after many reloads.

I need this parameter in the controller, there is at the moment no chance that the app can change the parameter or send an other parameter with the date value.

Do I have to do some configurations or something else?

I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: If you are sending **If-Modified-Since** and Symfony removing **if_modified_since**, then what is the problem. Symfony use this **if_modified_since** for its internal caching validation purpose. It never removes **If-Modified-Since** header.

Comment: You indeed need to configure [http cache](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html). Maybe you forgot to [wrap the kernel](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#symfony2-reverse-proxy) in `web/app.php`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems in your prod env you are using `app/AppCache.php` instead of `app/AppKernel.php`
So, in short if you want to handle it yourself switch back to `app/AppKernel.php` in your `web/app.php`

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
```

In details you should read about [Symfony http cache](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html)